# Firebase - ng deploy with angular, no data returned

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to connect to firebase locally with my application, but when I deploy, no data is being returned, and no error is shown.  I'm still learning the ins and outs, but I've been stuck on this for a while.

I've tried the tutorials, but nothing seems to work.